# Regex over multiple lines with special characters

Tags: regex

I am hoping someone can help me with this regex. I've only used it to collect single words in a string, so I'm not sure how to handle multiple lines and what look like ASCII characters.

Here is the text block:

```
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00003 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Recovery from 05/09/2012 at 09:17:50 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00020 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Information recovery starts on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:50 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00021 - Traitement        - Processing        - ---->  File processing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prog\Prog RIT\Web Orders\live\Prog Import\Order_110039354.tab
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00005 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  End of information recovery on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:51 AM 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00006 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records read 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00008 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records processed 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00010 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 integrated records 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00015 - Traitement        - Processing        -    ->  No integration errors 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00020 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Information recovery starts on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:51 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00021 - Traitement        - Processing        - ---->  File processing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prog\Prog RIT\Web Orders\live\Prog Import\Order_110039355.tab
Third-party       -  : La raison sociale doit �tre renseign�e 
Third-party       - _SHIP : La raison sociale doit �tre renseign�e 
Erreur            - RETAILEAIDOC00008 - Document          - Document          - address The internal reference enables the recovery of a document. It is mandatory 
Erreur            - RETAILEAIDOC00008 - Document          - Document          - address The internal reference enables the recovery of a document. It is mandatory 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00005 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  End of information recovery on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:52 AM 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00006 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records read 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00008 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records processed 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00012 - Traitement        - Processing        -    ->  No records integrated 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00013 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records contain errors 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00003 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Recovery from 05/09/2012 at 09:33:03 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00020 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Information recovery starts on 05/09/2012 at 09:33:03 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00021 - Traitement        - Processing        - ---->  File processing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prog\Prog RIT\Web Orders\live\Prog Import\Order_110039356.tab
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00005 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  End of information recovery on 05/09/2012 at 09:33:05 AM 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00006 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records read 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00008 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records processed 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00010 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 integrated records 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00015 - Traitement        - Processing        -    ->  No integration errors 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00020 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Information recovery starts on 05/09/2012 at 09:33:05 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00021 - Traitement        - Processing        - ---->  File processing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prog\Prog RIT\Web Orders\live\Prog Import\Order_110039357.tab
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00005 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  End of information recovery on 05/09/2012 at 09:33:06 AM 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00006 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records read 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00008 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 records processed 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00010 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 6 integrated records 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00015 - Traitement        - Processing        -    ->  No integration errors
```

However, I only want this segment:

```
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00020 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  Information recovery starts on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:51 AM 

Information       - RETAILEAITRT00021 - Traitement        - Processing        - ---->  File processing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Prog\Prog RIT\Web Orders\live\Prog Import\Order_110039355.tab
Third-party       -  : La raison sociale doit �tre renseign�e 
Third-party       - _SHIP : La raison sociale doit �tre renseign�e 
Erreur            - RETAILEAIDOC00008 - Document          - Document          - address The internal reference enables the recovery of a document. It is mandatory 
Erreur            - RETAILEAIDOC00008 - Document          - Document          - address The internal reference enables the recovery of a document. It is mandatory 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00005 - Traitement        - Processing        - --->  End of information recovery on 05/09/2012 at 09:17:52 AM 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00006 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records read 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00008 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records processed 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00012 - Traitement        - Processing        -    ->  No records integrated 
Information       - RETAILEAITRT00013 - Traitement        - Processing        -    -> 4 records contain errors
```

There are also some special characters there that appear as weird question marks. I just don't really know where to start with it really.. I guess it will have to look for ^Erreur, then grab the lines above and below it until it finds ^ with white space...?

Thanks

Comment: It's not especially clear what your criteria for the match are. You said looking up and down until you find a line with white space, but in your example above it includes the line above the first white-space only line. What defining criteria are there for a match?

Comment: This is three entries.. two with no errors, then one in between with an error. Each entry always starts with a line that says "Information recovery starts on". I want the whole block returned if there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the following regular expression:

```
Information.+recovery starts.+\n\n(?:.+\n)+(?:Erreur.+\n)+(?:.+\n)+
```

**Note: this requires the use of the "g" (global) flag** (tested successfuly in JavaScript). Not sure which language you're using, but it should have an equivalent flag.

And yes, it's extremely ugly :). Here's basically what it's looking for:

- A line that starts with "Information" and includes the words "recovery starts"
- Followed by an empty line
- Followed by at least one generic line
- Followed by at least one line that starts with "Erreur"
- Followed by any consecutive, non-whitespace-only lines

Comment: Excellent! You really got me up and running. I didn't get yours working exactly as it was. Did a fair bit of research and thinking of my own and came up with this one: Information.+recovery starts.+\n(?:.+\n){5}Erreur(?:.+\n)(?:.+\n){5} - a little more rigid, but I'll test it and it should do the trick. Thanks again!